# Do you find it unfair to mark as solution a latter answer when it's the same as the earlier one?

Tags: discussion

I've seen it happening before, that someone asked a question, and somebody answered it, and it was the actual solution too, then later, *a few (5-10) minutes later* someone else had answered as well, and it was almost the exact same answer, and the OP marked the latter answer as a solution and said thank only to him, also no upvote for the earlier answer

It's completely up to the OP, that which answer he/she marks as a solution, but **in my opinion**, if the first answer was a solution too, that one should be accepted.

What do you guys/gals think about this?

Comment: Can you link to any examples of this? While you're right that it's completely up to the OP (which also means it's not "indecent" or anything), this scenario sounds... Odd. Without context/examples, anyway.

Comment: Users, especially new users, won't necessarily be paying attention to the time at which an answer is posted. If two answers are essentially the same, on the same question and have the same number of votes, it may just be a matter of whichever is at the top for it to be accepted (as they won't be sorted in any particular order if the default "votes" sort is enabled).

Comment: Surprisingly @Kendra, I can identify with the OP and have had this happen before many times. Although I can't find any specific examples right now to link to, this can sometimes be a problem, specifically among newer users due to their lack of experience (as Nick noted).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've seen this occur on a few occasions on a number of sites (rarely on [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/) due to its nature) and generally this occurs with newer users who are simply looking for an answer, rather than more experienced users who may be looking to give the accept to whoever answered correctly first (perhaps out of fairness).

By default, answers to a question are sorted by votes, and in the case of a low traffic question it's not unlikely that you'll get two answers that are:

1. Pretty similar, and
2. Lacking votes

Because of this you may have two answers both with 0 votes and spread apart by several minutes. In this case the sorting algorithm used won't take into account post time, but will simply order the answers randomly, as can be seen by refreshing the page multiple times.

At this point, if the OP has been away for any period of time and missed the answers actually getting posted, then they may well read and thank the one at the top of the list, not giving the one right below a second glance.

I wouldn't think anything of it in most cases.

Comment: It is worth noting that the answers being sorted randomly is [a feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6662/how-to-give-some-boost-to-some-really-good-answers-that-arrive-late/10553#comment35066_10553).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is unfair.  The OP has selected the Answer that *in their opinion* is the most helpful *to them*.  If two Answers offer the same solution, there may be attributes other than speed to answer that make one Answer more helpful than the others.  For example:

- One may be may be written more clearly and accurately.
- One may be better formatted, have fewer typos, spelling / grammatical errors, etc<sup>1</sup>.
- One may provide additional information that the OP finds useful.

Ultimately, it is entirely up to the OP to decide which Answer to choose as the best.  We should not be questioning peoples' rationale / motivation for doing this ... or voting, or ...

Finally, one viewpoint is that voting and accepting are primarily used to rank Questions and Answers according to their usefulness.  This helps to direct people searching for and reading answers to ones that are more likely to help them.  From this viewpoint, it is counter-productive to encourage people to answer quickly instead of answering well.

---

<sup>1 - And who are we to say that this shouldn't influence the OP's decision about what to accept!</sup>